# Can somebody explain how SharedPreferences stores a string set

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I was trying to save a list of names in shared preferences and wanted to make use of the `SharedPreferences` `putStringSet` so that I won't need multiple key-value pairs.
 I know a regular `HashSet` doesn't guarantee iteration order so I used a `LinkedHashSet` to maintain the iteration order as the order of insertion and saved that to shared preferences.

When retrieving the same String Set I also used a `LinkedHashSet` but the order was not the same as when originally inserted.

I solved the problem by just storing the names in a comma separated string then parsing that, so that's not my question.

I would like to know what `SharedPreferences` does to a set of strings so that it does not maintain the correct ordering (at least not the one I want)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question in short  it un-links your linked hash set by creating a simple HashSet from your values... from that point on - no links of order.

From source code:

```
public Editor putStringSet(String key, Set<String> values) {
        synchronized (this) {
            mModified.put(key,
                    (values == null) ? null : new HashSet<String>(values));
            return this;
        }
    }
```

Thats why, like you did, if you want to preserve order you need to store as string with separators (you used coma) and then split the separator to get an array.

Comment: Pretty straightforward I guess. Thanks, gotta look at source code more often.

Comment: yep. I often do. And then end up having to extend a lot of native classes to add custom functionality... :-)

Answer (score -1):

There is one trick I use often is `JSON`. 
It is very easy to convert complex objects to `JSON` and that save them as simple string into `SharedPreferences`.
You just need few lines of code to do this.

Have a look at popular `JSON` libraries like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) and [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

Here is an util class you can use to convert object into `JSON` and vice versa.

```
public class JsonUtils {
    private JsonUtils() {
    }
    public static String convertObjectToJSONString(Object object) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonObject = "";
        try {
            jsonObject = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }
    public static<T> T parseObjectFromString(String json,Class<T> objectClass) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        T object = null;
        try {
            object = objectMapper.readValue(json, objectClass);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return object;
    }
}
```

If you still want to save `String Set` into shared preference this is on thing you should not miss is to remove old set and than insert new one.

```
Set<String> stringSet = sharedPrefs.getStringSet("set-key", new HashSet<String>());
            stringSet.add("Hello World");
            Editor edit = sharedPrefs.edit();
            edit.remove("set-key");
            edit.apply();
            edit.putStringSet("set-key", stringSet);
```

Also you can just use plain old `ObjectOutputStream` to convert object into `byte[]` or `String` and than save it. But as a lot of people noticed this is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: How does this answer the question of how to store a `Set` of Strings?

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question but will be useful in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @p1g1n I have just updated the unswer please have a look

Comment: This is a nice trick. Unfortunately 2 things. Using HashSet will mix the entry values without preserving order. The poster is looking to preserve exact order which is diffifult to achieve with native class messing it up. and secondly, you should not use commit() but apply() unless you're on a background thread.